# link_to is not creating the required route using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Sortable Table Columns in my application. I have application controller like below:

```
module ApplicationHelper  
  def sortable(column, title = nil)  
    title ||= column.titleize  
    direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction  
  end  
end
```

in my view I have the below code for sorting:

```
<tr>  
  <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>  
  <th><%= sortable "price" %></th>  
  <th><%= sortable "released_at", "Released" %></th>  
</tr>
```

Now when I mouse over on name link it shows URL like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/?direction=asc&sort=name`

But I want this URL like  `http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/promotions?direction=asc&sort=name`

My questions is why it doesn't include the controller etc by itself or I would include it myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to give the controller / action or path yourself:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Title is the field name not a controller.